# How laravel defines a related table to a model that will be executed to get some data?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a table called "articles" and migrated it into database .

I have run `php artisan make:model Articles` to create a model

after that I have create a controller called "ArticlesContoller"

then I have create a method , fo example :

```
....
use App/Article; // it s the model

class ArticleController extends Controller{

function getall(){
return Article::All(); //or whatever can give a result
}
 ...
```

now I have this route

```
Route::get('/test','AriclesController@getall);
```

and finally I got all the data from "article" Table;

the question is Why I m getting data from table while the model is empty???

and how that the app know that this model linked to article table in database?
because I didn't add any relation between them I just follow the steps and I didn't found any relation on these steps.
if anyone can explain.
thanks.

Comment: As long as you follow the Laravel naming schema, it'll use the plural of whatever the model is called. So the `Article` model becomes `articles` table. A `Post` model becomes `posts` table. You can overwrite it by defining `protected $table = 'my_custom_article_table';` in the model's class if you want to overwrite it.

Comment: You can verify it by checking out the source, https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1381

Comment: thank you so much , I will check it :)